# RewriteRule not working properly in my Ubuntu server 14.04 running in Windows Azure

Tags: htaccess, apache, server, ubuntu, azure

In my server I kept `signup.php` and in *.htaccess* I kept this thing -

> RewriteRule ^/registration/?$ http://www.example.com/signup$1 [R]

But this is not redirecting `www.example.com/registration/` to `www.example.com/signup/` 
However I tried with other things like -

> RewriteRule ^/registration/?$ signup.php$1 [R]

and also -

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^registration/$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)
>   http://example.com/signup [R=301,L

But nothing is working out. It's showing me 404 error message. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in Windows Azure server running Apache 2.2.22

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems with your rewrite rules.

- You don't explicitly turn on mod_rewrite with `RewriteEngine On`
- When using rewrite rules in your *.htaccess* file the slash at the beginning of them is assumed.  Having a slash at the beginning of the rule will prevent rewrite from executing the rule.  (This is different than if the rule were in *httpd.conf* where the slash at the beginning is required.)
- You have an extraneous `$1` in your first rule.  Having `$1` should be a back reference to whatever is in parenthesis  in the first part of the rule.   There are no parenthesis, so that rule is not going to work right.
- When redirecting with mod_rewrite, I recommend always using the `L` flag to ensure that it is the last rewrite rule triggered.
- You almost always want to specify the "permanent" type of redirect with `R=301` so that it doesn't do temporary redirect which are less SEO friendly.
- Your last rule should be on multiple lines.
- Your last rule is missing a closing `]`.

I would recommend first trying to use a simple redirect directive for something this simple:

```
redirect permanent /registration /signup
```

If that doesn't work you can fix your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^registration/?$ /signup [L,R=301]
```